# How to insert subnode in xml file using xmlstarlet or any bash command

Tags: xml, bash, xmlstarlet

I have multiple xml files where i want to update a subnode if the subnode project points to different project or insert a subnode if it doesn't exist.

I have been able to update the subnode project if it doesn't point to the right project using xml starlet command, but i am not able to insert subnode project if the project tag doesn't exist.

I have tried.

```
xmlstarlet ed -P --update "///module[@id='pxc110237_1']/@project" -v"X1" --insert"///module[@id='pxc110237_1']/@project --type attr -n style -v"X1" file.xml
```

The original File:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <kgcontent>
    <containers>
       <module project="ANY" level="1" id="pxc110233_1"/>
       <module project="X1" level="1" id="pxc110234_1"/>
       <module id="pxc110235_1"/>
    </containers>
  <kgcontent>
```

I want the output to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <kgcontent>
    <containers>
       <module project="ANY" level="1" id="pxc110233_1"/>
       <module project="X1" level="1" id="pxc110234_1"/>
       <module project="X1" id="pxc110235_1"/>
    </containers>
  <kgcontent>
```

The starlet command i used doesn't have any effect on the file. how can i fix the above problem? any pointers would be great help

Thank you!

Comment: Given your example using this command; `xml ed -P --inplace -a "//module[not(@project)]" -t attr -n "project" -v "X1" file.xml` will add an attribute named `project` to all `<module>` element nodes, that do not already have a `project` attribute, and set it's value to `X1`. Is that what you want ?